# Change Mac FN key behaviour on external keyboard

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, osx-elcapitan

normally MacOS runs special functions when hitting the F-Keys (i.e. Setting the volume or display brightness). To get the application specific F function you have to combine it with FN+F. You can change that behavour in the keyboard settings so that the F keys invoke their application function without FN. Unfortunately this does not work for my external logitech keyboard.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Does your Logitech keyboard have "F-Lock" key?

Comment: No unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) to solve a similar problem. The UI is terribly confusing, but should allow you to activate some modifiers when using your laptop's keyboard but not an external one, or vice versa.

Comment: I will try this. But I am sure the native setting worked also on the external keyboard before el-capitan.

Comment: @Imontrieux I cannot find any suitable option in Karabiner. Can you post the correct parameters in Karabiner?

Comment: Ok I found the suitable option, but it does not work on my logitech K750 as the FN behaviour is handled internally in the keyboard hardware. Thanks for the nice suggestion anyway.